# joomla - Storing user parameters in custom component issue

Tags: database, joomla, parameters, components

Hi for my custom component I need to set some custom parameters for joomla user for membership for checking if the user ni trial period or not and it can be change from the component admin panel for specific user.

The problem arises while retrieving the parameter. I think it is stored in cookie and it isn^t updated. I wrote the code like that to check it.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser(JRequest::getVar('id','0'));
echo $user->getParam('trialPeriod','0');
```

to save the value I am useing JHTML booleanlist.

```
$user->setParam('trialPeriod',$data['trialPeriod']);
$user->save();
```

Then is stores the value in joomla users table in the row of that user with column of params as;

```
{"trialPeriod":"0"}
```

in this situation it echoes the value as 0. Then I am changin the state of trialPeriod var as 1 and storing in db it updates the db as;

```
{"trialPeriod":"1"}
```

After all I am refreshing the page where the value is prompt the the screen the the value remains still the same as 0;

To clarify;

First of all there is no problem with saving the param it is changed properly. The problem is retrieving the changed one. The releated piece of code is following;

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

if($user->getParam('trialPeriod',0) == 0){
    $ed = JFactory::getDate($obj->expirationDate);//obj is user from custom table and there is no problem with getting it.
    $isTrialEnd = FALSE;
}else{
    $ed = JFactory::getDate($user->getParam('trialExp',0));
    $isTrialEnd = TRUE;
}
if($isTrialEnd){
    //do something else
}else{
    echo $user->getParam('trialPeriod','0');
}
```

actually big part of the code is unneccessary to explain it but you will get the idea.

What is the solution for this?

Editted.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $db     = $this->getDbo();

    $isNew = empty($data['uid']) ? true : false;
    $params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_dratransport');
    if($isNew){

        // Initialise the table with JUser.
        $user   = new JUser;

        // Prepare the data for the user object.
        $username = self::getCreatedUserName($data['type']);
        $data['username']   = !empty($data['username']) ? $data['username'] : $username;
        $data['password']   = $data['password1'];

        $useractivation = $params->get('useractivation');

        // Check if the user needs to activate their account.
        if (($useractivation == 1) || ($useractivation == 2)) {
            $data['activation'] = JApplication::getHash(JUserHelper::genRandomPassword());
            $data['block'] = 1;
        }

    }else{          

        $user   = JFactory::getUser($data['uid']);
        $data['password']   = $data['password1'];

    }

    $membership = DraTransportHelperArrays::membershipCFG();
    $membership = $membership[$data['membership']];

    if($data['membership'] == 4)
        $data['groups']     = array($params->get('new_usertype',2),$params->get($membership,2));
    else
        $data['groups']     = array($params->get($membership,2));



    $data['name']       = $data['companyName'];
    $user->setParam('trialPeriod',$data['trialPeriod']);

    // Bind the data.
    if (!$user->bind($data)) {
        $this->setError(JText::sprintf('COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_BIND_FAILED', $user->getError()));
        return false;
    }

    // Load the users plugin group.
    JPluginHelper::importPlugin('user');

    // Store the data.
    if (!$user->save()) {
        $app->enqueuemessage($user->getError());
        $this->setError(JText::sprintf('COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_SAVE_FAILED', $user->getError()));
        return false;
    }
```

this piece of code is for storing the data releated with the users table.

Comment: I have tested this and it appears to work fine. Are you trying to store this for a valid user (i.e, the `JRequest::getVar('id','0')` returns a valid user id - `0` is usually _not_ a valid id)? There could be an error storing the data if the user is invalid. You can try to get that some insight by executing `echo 'id is '.JRequest::getVar('id','0').' and error is: '.$user->getError();`

Comment: I am sorry I did some mistake the above code Jrequest is for admin page and it takes the proper value since after the redirection the radio buttons check state is changeing and to see the state in frontend I am getting the JUser without any id to get the current user. Then I am checking if it is logged in or not as $user->guest == 0 if it is true it is written on the page but the old value.

Comment: please show the part that stores the data, regardless if it is functioning or not. You should make it as easy as possible for people to help you solve your issue. Please do so by editing your original question.

Comment: MasterAM thanks for your concern :)

Comment: If I were you, I would set my Joomla installation debugging mode to `on` in order to view all of the queries and use my favorite debugger to step through code and see what is loaded, what is skipped and why.

Comment: In debuging mode joomla crashes with the jcomment componenet I did not understand why. But I realized that if I retrive the user object like this;

    $user = JUser::getInstance(JFactory::getUser()->id);
    echo $user->params;

works correctly. I think it is caused by calling the JFactory::getUser() multiple times causes the instances crossing. Is this true?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your code looks like, but it is better to simply use `JFactory::getUser()` in order to get the current user. There is no problem getting multiple users by specifying their `id`s `JFactory::getUser($id)`.

Comment: What happens when I call the JFactory::getUser() for multiple times in order to get the current user. Of course this usage is mistake but some times I can pass some points in the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36981/discussion-between-masteram-and-freezer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was the fact that Joomla stores the `JUser` instance in the session that caused the problem.

When changing a user's parameters from the back-end, the changes are not reflected in that user's session, until she logs out and back in again.

We could not find an easy option to modify anther user's active session, so we resorted to the use of a plugin that refreshes the JUser instance in the logged-in users' session, something like the following:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$session = JFactory::getSession();

if(!$user->guest) {
    $session->set('user', new JUser($user->id));
}
```

(reference: [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2658563)).